# Forming a post to a SOAP api with npm request

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, request

I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
POST /oms/order.asmx HTTP/1.1  
Host:myserver.com 
Content-Type: text/xml; 
charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: length  
SOAPAction: "http://shipping_software/AddOrder"
```

By doing this:

```
var newOrder = buildOrder(orderInfo);
var soapOptions = {
    uri: '/oms/order.asmx',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'charset': 'utf-8',
        'Content-Length': newOrder.length.toString(),
        'SOAPAction': 'http://shipping_software/AddOrder',
        'Host': 'myserver.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: newOrder //New order is properly formed xml as a String
}
request(soapOptions, function(err, response) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(response);
    })
    // console.log(newOrder);
});
```

This currently comes back with 'invalid uri', when I change the URI to `http://myserver.com/oms/order.asmx` I still get a 400 response code.

**Edit:** I fixed the content type to be on one line `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` without any improvement.

**Edit2:**  I'm using XMLBuilder to build my XML data and tried submitting it without converting it to a string, however the connection from the SOAP API times out.

**Edit3:** full soap request:

```
POST /oms/order.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://oms/AddOrder"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://sma-promail/">
      <Username>string</Username>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </AuthenticationHeader>
    <DebugHeader xmlns="http://sma-promail/">
      <Debug>boolean</Debug>
      <Request>string</Request>
    </DebugHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AddOrder xmlns="http://sma-promail/">
      <order>
        <Header>
          <ID>string</ID>
          <EntryDate>dateTime</EntryDate>
          <OrderEntryView>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </OrderEntryView>
          <ReferenceNumber>string</ReferenceNumber>
          <PONumber>string</PONumber>
          <Comments>string</Comments>
          <IpAddress>string</IpAddress>
          <ApprovalComment>string</ApprovalComment>
          <InsertDate>dateTime</InsertDate>
        </Header>
        <Classification>
          <CampaignID>string</CampaignID>
          <ResponseMedia>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </ResponseMedia>
          <Source>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </Source>
          <Issue>
            <Issue>string</Issue>
          </Issue>
          <CustomerProject>
            <ID>string</ID>
          </CustomerProject>
          <CustomerCode>string</CustomerCode>
          <Store>string</Store>
          <Department>string</Department>
          <DistributionCenter>string</DistributionCenter>
          <Vendor>string</Vendor>
        </Classification>
        <Shipping>
          <FreightCarrier>
            <Name>string</Name>
          </FreightCarrier>
          <FreightService>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </FreightService>
          <FreightAccount>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <Description>string</Description>
            <FreightCarrier xsi:nil="true" />
            <Person xsi:nil="true" />
            <ThirdAcctNo>string</ThirdAcctNo>
            <NonResident>boolean</NonResident>
          </FreightAccount>
          <ShippingOption>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </ShippingOption>
          <FreightCode>string</FreightCode>
          <FreightCodeDescription>string</FreightCodeDescription>
          <ShipComments>string</ShipComments>
          <NeededBy>string</NeededBy>
          <Rush>boolean</Rush>
          <ReleaseDate>dateTime</ReleaseDate>
          <ThirdPartyType>int</ThirdPartyType>
          <ThirdAccountNumber>string</ThirdAccountNumber>
          <NCShip>boolean</NCShip>
          <NCPack>boolean</NCPack>
          <NCOffers>boolean</NCOffers>
          <NCHandling>boolean</NCHandling>
          <NCOffShipHandling>boolean</NCOffShipHandling>
          <NCSpecialHandling>boolean</NCSpecialHandling>
          <NCRush>boolean</NCRush>
        </Shipping>
        <Money>
          <PriceClass>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </PriceClass>
          <ShippingHandlingCharge>decimal</ShippingHandlingCharge>
          <RushHandlingCharge>decimal</RushHandlingCharge>
          <NoChargeType>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </NoChargeType>
          <DiscountAmount>decimal</DiscountAmount>
          <DiscountPercent>float</DiscountPercent>
          <DiscountCode>
            <ID>string</ID>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </DiscountCode>
          <Coupon>
            <Code>string</Code>
          </Coupon>
          <SpecialHandlingCharge>decimal</SpecialHandlingCharge>
          <CreditAmount>decimal</CreditAmount>
          <GiftCertificate>
            <UID>string</UID>
            <Amount>decimal</Amount>
          </GiftCertificate>
          <GiftCertificateAmount>decimal</GiftCertificateAmount>
          <TaxPercent>decimal</TaxPercent>
          <NoChargeAmount>decimal</NoChargeAmount>
          <TaxAmount>decimal</TaxAmount>
        </Money>
        <Payment>
          <PaymentType>
            <Description>string</Description>
            <Sequence>int</Sequence>
          </PaymentType>
          <PaymentAmount>decimal</PaymentAmount>
          <CCNumber>string</CCNumber>
          <CCExpirationDate>string</CCExpirationDate>
          <CSC>string</CSC>
          <ARReference>string</ARReference>
        </Payment>
        <OrderVariables>
          <OrderVariable>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <VariableField xsi:nil="true" />
            <Value>string</Value>
          </OrderVariable>
          <OrderVariable>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <VariableField xsi:nil="true" />
            <Value>string</Value>
          </OrderVariable>
        </OrderVariables>
        <OrderedBy>
          <ORDOBY>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <CustomerID>string</CustomerID>
          </ORDOBY>
          <FullName>string</FullName>
          <FullNameWithSuffix>string</FullNameWithSuffix>
          <CityStateZip>string</CityStateZip>
          <CityStateZipCountry>string</CityStateZipCountry>
          <CompoundAddress>string</CompoundAddress>
        </OrderedBy>
        <ShipTo>
          <OrderShipTo>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <Flag>Other or OrderedBy</Flag>
            <Key>string</Key>
            <NeededBy>string</NeededBy>
            <ReleaseDate>dateTime</ReleaseDate>
            <Rush>boolean</Rush>
            <RushHandling>decimal</RushHandling>
            <Comments>string</Comments>
            <FreightCarrier xsi:nil="true" />
            <FreightService xsi:nil="true" />
            <ThirdPartyType>int</ThirdPartyType>
            <ThirdPartyAccountNumber>string</ThirdPartyAccountNumber>
            <FreightCode>string</FreightCode>
            <FreightCodeDescription>string</FreightCodeDescription>
            <SpecialHandling xsi:nil="true" />
            <SpecialHandlingCharge>decimal</SpecialHandlingCharge>
            <ShippingHandlingCharge>decimal</ShippingHandlingCharge>
            <FullName>string</FullName>
            <FullNameWithSuffix>string</FullNameWithSuffix>
            <CityStateZip>string</CityStateZip>
            <CityStateZipCountry>string</CityStateZipCountry>
            <CompoundAddress>string</CompoundAddress>
            <PickPacks xsi:nil="true" />
          </OrderShipTo>
          <OrderShipTo>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <Flag>Other or OrderedBy</Flag>
            <Key>string</Key>
            <NeededBy>string</NeededBy>
            <ReleaseDate>dateTime</ReleaseDate>
            <Rush>boolean</Rush>
            <RushHandling>decimal</RushHandling>
            <Comments>string</Comments>
            <FreightCarrier xsi:nil="true" />
            <FreightService xsi:nil="true" />
            <ThirdPartyType>int</ThirdPartyType>
            <ThirdPartyAccountNumber>string</ThirdPartyAccountNumber>
            <FreightCode>string</FreightCode>
            <FreightCodeDescription>string</FreightCodeDescription>
            <SpecialHandling xsi:nil="true" />
            <SpecialHandlingCharge>decimal</SpecialHandlingCharge>
            <ShippingHandlingCharge>decimal</ShippingHandlingCharge>
            <FullName>string</FullName>
            <FullNameWithSuffix>string</FullNameWithSuffix>
            <CityStateZip>string</CityStateZip>
            <CityStateZipCountry>string</CityStateZipCountry>
            <CompoundAddress>string</CompoundAddress>
            <PickPacks xsi:nil="true" />
          </OrderShipTo>
        </ShipTo>
        <BillTo>
          <Flag>Other or OrderedBy or DoNotUse or ShipTo</Flag>
          <FullName>string</FullName>
          <FullNameWithSuffix>string</FullNameWithSuffix>
          <CityStateZip>string</CityStateZip>
          <CityStateZipCountry>string</CityStateZipCountry>
          <CompoundAddress>string</CompoundAddress>
        </BillTo>
        <Offers>
          <OfferOrdered>
            <Offer xsi:nil="true" />
            <Quantity>int</Quantity>
            <CanceledQuantity>int</CanceledQuantity>
            <OrderShipTo xsi:nil="true" />
            <OrderShipToKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <PriceType>unsignedByte</PriceType>
            <UnitPrice>decimal</UnitPrice>
            <ShipType>short</ShipType>
            <ShippingHandling>decimal</ShippingHandling>
            <Discounts>decimal</Discounts>
            <DiscountPercent>int</DiscountPercent>
            <DocumentID>string</DocumentID>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <CloneLine>int</CloneLine>
            <Unapproved>boolean</Unapproved>
            <ShipToKey>string</ShipToKey>
            <FgnOrder>string</FgnOrder>
            <Comments>string</Comments>
            <RCOrderKey>string</RCOrderKey>
            <Recurring>boolean</Recurring>
            <LineNumber>int</LineNumber>
            <Variables xsi:nil="true" />
            <ProductDetails xsi:nil="true" />
          </OfferOrdered>
          <OfferOrdered>
            <Offer xsi:nil="true" />
            <Quantity>int</Quantity>
            <CanceledQuantity>int</CanceledQuantity>
            <OrderShipTo xsi:nil="true" />
            <OrderShipToKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <PriceType>unsignedByte</PriceType>
            <UnitPrice>decimal</UnitPrice>
            <ShipType>short</ShipType>
            <ShippingHandling>decimal</ShippingHandling>
            <Discounts>decimal</Discounts>
            <DiscountPercent>int</DiscountPercent>
            <DocumentID>string</DocumentID>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <CloneLine>int</CloneLine>
            <Unapproved>boolean</Unapproved>
            <ShipToKey>string</ShipToKey>
            <FgnOrder>string</FgnOrder>
            <Comments>string</Comments>
            <RCOrderKey>string</RCOrderKey>
            <Recurring>boolean</Recurring>
            <LineNumber>int</LineNumber>
            <Variables xsi:nil="true" />
            <ProductDetails xsi:nil="true" />
          </OfferOrdered>
        </Offers>
        <OrderRecurrenceSchedule>
          <RecurrenceSchedules>
            <SeqID>int</SeqID>
            <ID>string</ID>
            <Description>string</Description>
            <Definition>string</Definition>
            <DefinitionDetail>string</DefinitionDetail>
            <Schedule>EveryXDays or EveryXWeeks or EveryXMonths</Schedule>
            <ScheduleCount>int</ScheduleCount>
            <Cycle>Rolling or Custom</Cycle>
            <StartCycleDate>dateTime</StartCycleDate>
            <DaysToJoin>int</DaysToJoin>
            <MonthlyRecurrenceType>DayOfMonth or WeekOfMonthAndDayOfWeek</MonthlyRecurrenceType>
            <MinimumRecurrences>int</MinimumRecurrences>
            <MaximumRecurrences>int</MaximumRecurrences>
            <RecurrenceIncrement>int</RecurrenceIncrement>
            <AllowInfiniteRecurrence>boolean</AllowInfiniteRecurrence>
            <InfiniteTag>string</InfiniteTag>
            <DurationTag>string</DurationTag>
            <ExpirationDate>dateTime</ExpirationDate>
            <NextCycleDate>dateTime</NextCycleDate>
            <HasValidCycleDate>boolean</HasValidCycleDate>
            <AnyOffer>boolean</AnyOffer>
            <RecurrenceScheduleShippingOptions xsi:nil="true" />
          </RecurrenceSchedules>
          <RecurrenceOfferFlag>boolean</RecurrenceOfferFlag>
          <RecurrenceShippingOption>
            <Description>string</Description>
          </RecurrenceShippingOption>
          <RecurrenceSpecialHandlingCharge>decimal</RecurrenceSpecialHandlingCharge>
          <NumberRecurrence>int</NumberRecurrence>
        </OrderRecurrenceSchedule>
        <OrderBudget>
          <Person>
            <Name xsi:nil="true" />
            <CompanyInfo xsi:nil="true" />
            <Address xsi:nil="true" />
            <ContactInfo xsi:nil="true" />
            <BillingInfo xsi:nil="true" />
            <Variables xsi:nil="true" />
          </Person>
        </OrderBudget>
      </order>
    </AddOrder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <DebugHeader xmlns="http://sma-promail/">
      <Debug>boolean</Debug>
      <Request>string</Request>
    </DebugHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AddOrderResponse xmlns="http://sma-promail/">
      <AddOrderResult>
        <OrderSeqID>int</OrderSeqID>
        <OrderID>string</OrderID>
      </AddOrderResult>
    </AddOrderResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hard to figure out where it's going wrong - the HTTP request excerpt you've added there isn't complete (or at least, you've added those as headers in your Node.js code, but they don't all look like headers). Can you make a successful request with [tag:curl]? If so, post that complete curl command in your question.

Comment: The headers appear to be set correctly:

_header: 'POST /oms/order.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\ncharset: utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 1161\r\nSOAPAction: http://oms/AddOrder\r\nHost: myserver.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'

Comment: Honestly without seeing a complete HTTP request, it's going to be impossible to figure out why your server is throwing back the 400.

Comment: The rest of the http request is just the xml

Comment: This isn't directly related to the problem, but have you considered using a module like [`soap`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) that makes it much easier to work with SOAP endpoints?

Comment: @mscdex I have, unfortunately I couldn't find the licensing.

Comment: @WilliamChantry There's a [`LICENSE`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/LICENSE) file in the repo and it's the MIT license.

Comment: Ah, the file in all caps in the root of the project.

Comment: @mscdex I actually find the soap module a little more confusing than request.

Answer (score 2):

It goes slightly off topic from the post title, but I ended up just going with node http:

```
var newOrder = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope><soap:Header>.....</soap:Envelope>"

    var postOptions = {
      hostname: 'server.com',
      port: 80,
      path: '/oms/order.asmx?wsdl',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Host':'server.com',
        'Content-Type':'text/xml;charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length':newOrder.length,
        'SOAPAction':"http://sma-promail/AddOrder", 
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(postOptions, function(res) {
      console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    // write data to request body
    req.write(newOrder);
    req.end();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Speculation thus far, but assuming all the headers are set up properly, the one thing that stands out is the `content-type` header - you've got the type and charset split into multiple key:value pairs; it should be on a single line:

```
var newOrder = buildOrder(orderInfo);
var soapOptions = {
    uri: 'http://myserver.com/oms/order.asmx',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length': newOrder.length.toString(),
        'SOAPAction': 'http://shipping_software/AddOrder',
        'Host': 'myserver.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: newOrder //New order is properly formed xml as a String
}
request(soapOptions, function(err, response) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(response);
    })
    // console.log(newOrder);
});
```

Also, as you stated in your question, make sure `uri` is a fully qualified URL, not just the path suffix.

Comment: Ok - try and get it to work with curl. If you can, please add that command to your question.

Comment: I've been trying to get a curl soap call to work, however nothing is returned:

curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' -H 'Content-Length: 1150' -H 'SOAPAction:http://sma-promail/AddOrder' --data @sampleOrder.txt http://myserver.com/pmomsws/order.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Hrm, ok well if you can't get that working, that's definitely the problem. I'd suggest finding some docs on your server or find a working request example.

Comment: Could it be that I'm missing something in my xml string?  I would think it would still make a connection and just respond with an error stating I'm missing something.

Comment: Without knowing what your server is doing or what it expects, it's like searching for a needle in a field of haystacks :(

Comment: I do have that docs, however they don't seem to be put together well (a couple inconsistencies) http://pmdev.gloful.com/pmomsws/order.asmx?op=AddOrder